# Is there anything wrong with having "one" endpoint to service multiple "types" of requests?

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, message-queue, messaging

Let's say for example I have some pizza delivery service. Types of things it can do are

- `CreateOrder`
- `CancelOrder`
- `GetOrderStatus`

for example. The API layer of my service might expose these as "separate" endpoints like `/order (POST)`, `/order (DELETE)`, etc. and these are somehow routed to a worker layer that processes the requests.

Is it OK to make the worker receive requests through a single message queue where messages are like

```
{
    id: "47a4aa26-295c-4163-9701-b6c20863643a",
    type: "order-create",
    payload: {
         size: "xl",
         toppings: ["canadianBacon", "pineapple"]
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    id: "4278dd527-6c4f-4bee-b8f6-0871af0b39ce",
    type: "order-cancel",
    payload: {
         orderId: "dff1b7e4-0c07-4327-8590-ac71065f32e5",
         cancellationDate: "Mon Oct 14 2019 09:24:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
    }
}
```

instead of having every different `type` of message go to a "separate" queue (or some other type of "separate" abstraction/infrastructure like a *topic* if using Azure Service Bus).

What I like about this is whenever there's a new type of business capability that I want my pizza delivery service to have, I just define a new `type` and `payload` contract and write a new handler, don't need to create any new infrastructure/routing/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be any problem as long as you have multiple consumer at Worker Layer and your queue has At-Least-Once delivery approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with having “one” endpoint to service multiple
>   “types” of requests?

Surely, you can build your service with only one endpoint but it is not a standard way!

What that means is you will miss out on tools which are build around maintaining API endpoints. You would basically have to reinvent the wheel to tackle API deprecation *(request type deprecation in your case)*, tech stack migration or payload change problem to name the few. Since all server frameworks follow the standard HTTP spec and Restful principles, many of the above concerns can be easily solved using framework APIs, if not, you can find tons of open source libraries to help you with that.

> What I like about this is whenever there's a new type of business
>   capability that I want my pizza delivery service to have, I just
>   define a new type and payload contract and write a new handler, don't
>   need to create any new infrastructure/routing/etc.

Last time I checked, defining a new API endpoint has become pretty declarative these days and framework generates the infrastructure and routing code for you. At least when I used Express, nodejs web framework, a while back.